# how to use touch screen controls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have this code to move the player, and I want to change the movement method

```
var dirs = new[]
        {
            (x - 1, y, hwalls, x, y, Vector3.right, 90, KeyCode.A),
            (x + 1, y, hwalls, x + 1, y, Vector3.right, 90, KeyCode.D),
            (x, y - 1, vwalls, x, y, Vector3.up, 0, KeyCode.S),
            (x, y + 1, vwalls, x, y + 1, Vector3.up, 0, KeyCode.W),
        };
        foreach (var (nx, ny, wall, wx, wy, sh, ang, k) in dirs.OrderBy(d => Random.value))
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(k))
                if (wall[wx, wy])
                    Player.position = Vector3.Lerp(Player.position, new Vector3(nx, ny), 0.1f);
                else (x, y) = (nx, ny);
```

and this is the swipe controller script

```
 if (fingerDown == false && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            startPos = Input.mousePosition;
            fingerDown = true;
        }
        if (fingerDown)
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.y >= startPos.y + pixelDistToDetect)
            {
                fingerDown = false;
                Debug.Log("up");
            }
            else if (Input.mousePosition.y <= startPos.y - pixelDistToDetect)
            {
                fingerDown = false;
                Debug.Log("down");
            }
            else if (Input.mousePosition.x <= startPos.x - pixelDistToDetect)
            {
                fingerDown = false;
                Debug.Log("left");
            }
            else if (Input.mousePosition.x >= startPos.x + pixelDistToDetect)
            {
                fingerDown = false;
                Debug.Log("right");
            }
        }
        if (fingerDown && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            fingerDown = false;
        }
```

the point of this is that I don't want to use the  `KeyCode.@`,
is there a way to call the keycode.@ by the swipe controller

Thanks

Comment: Use state pattern :v

Comment: I tried putting `KeyCode.Mouse0` instead of `KeyCode.@`, it worked, but whenever I press on the screen, it moves randomly

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! your code is clearly in `c#` ...

Comment: Is there a special reason why you handle your user input in random order ^^?